# Real embeddings and linear disjointness

Tags: field-theory

Suppose I have two Galois extensions $F_1, F_2$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $F_1$ has a real embedding. Then is there a general condition on $F_2$ such that $F_1$ and $F_2$ will be linearly disjoint (for example I think if $F_2$ is imaginary quadratic they will be linearly disjoint)?

Comment: Couldn't $F_1$ even be a subfield of $F_2$? For instance, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2},i)$.

Comment: ah ok, I have edited the question